# Value of $\cos\frac{\pi*n(n-1)}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove that $$\cos\frac{\pi n(n-1)}{2} = \Large(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$?

I've concluded that it's equal to $\sin\Large\frac{\pi n^2}{2}$ when **n** is odd to $\cos\Large\frac{\pi n^2}{2}$ even when **n** is even, but I don't know how to sum up all of that.

Comment: $\cos m\pi$ is $1$ for even $m$ and $-1$ for odd $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\ge1$, the expression $n(n-1)/2$ is the sum of all integers from $0$ up to $n-1$.

This sum starts out even (for $n=1$); the second term is obtained by adding $1$, which is odd; next we add $2$, giving again an odd term; next we add $3$, so the sum becomes even and stays at the next step. So the terms are

> even odd odd even even odd odd even …

because the same scheme repeats all over again. For $m$ even, $\cos(m\pi)=1$; for $m$ odd, $\cos(m\pi)=-1$. Since
$$
(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}
$$
satisfies the same requirement, you are done.

---

You can also do a more detailed proof by induction. The statement is clear for $n=1$.

Suppose it is for $n$. Then we want to compare
$$
f(n+1)=\cos\left(\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\pi\right)
\qquad\text{with}\qquad
g(n+1)=(-1)^{(n+1)n/2}
$$
given that $f(n)=g(n)$. Note that
$$
\frac{(n+1)n}{2}-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n}{2}(n+1-n+1)=n
$$
so if $h(n)=n(n-1)/2$, we have $h(n+1)=h(n)+n$. Then
\begin{align}
f(n+1)
&=\cos(h(n+1)\pi)\\
&=\cos(h(n)\pi+n\pi)\\
&=\cos(h(n)\pi)\cos(n\pi)-\sin(h(n)\pi)\sin(n\pi)\\
&=\cos(h(n)\pi)\cos(n\pi)\\
&=f(n)\cos(n\pi)\\
&=g(n)\cos(n\pi)\\
&=(-1)^{h(n)}\cos(n\pi)
\end{align}
by applying the induction hypothesis and the fact that $\sin(n\pi)=0$.

Now it's easy to see that $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$, so we can go on with
\begin{align}
&=(-1)^{h(n)}(-1)^n\\
&=(-1)^{h(n)+n}\\
&=(-1)^{h(n+1)}\\
&=g(n+1)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n(n-1)}2$$ is an integer and

$$\cos(m\pi)=\cos((m\bmod2)\pi),\\(-1)^m=(-1)^{m\bmod 2},$$

so that it suffices to check equality for $m=0$ and $m=1$.